# Is Swift ABI compatible between minor versions?

Tags: ios, swift

I know Swift is not yet [ABI stable](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md), but does that only count for major versions of Swift?

Is there any guarantee that minor or patch versions (under [semantic versioning](http://semver.org)) of Swift are ABI stable?

I'm guessing there is no guarantee here, but just wanted to double check if anyone has come across anything detailing ABI stability for different minor/patch versions of Swift.

Also, if I use a Swift binary framework compiled with a different version of Swift I get a compiler error usually. If I don't get a compiler error in my project does that mean it is safe, or could there still potentially be runtime issues with a slightly different (patch version) of Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 3**

We also have module stability, starting with Xcode 11, with the help of the newly introduced `.swiftinterface` files. One caveat, though, is that the code will have to be build with the `-enable-library-evolution` flag. More details [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-module-stability-and-module-interface-files/23337).

---

**Update 2** Module stability is scheduled for Swift 6: https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-more/#module-stability

This is an excerpt from the [Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/8d62e46b9b4a746331ea9b96fe60f82b50e41857/README.md#primary-focus-abi-stability) repo.

---

**Update** Swift 5 comes with *some* ABI stability:

> The Swift 5 release will provide ABI stability for the Swift Standard Library.

---

Unfortunately, not yet. For Swift 4, they state this here: https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-1-release-process/.

> Swift 4.1 is not binary compatible with 4.0. It contains a variety of under-the-hood changes that are part of the effort to stabilize the Swift ABI in Swift 5.

Hopefully we'll get ABI stability in Swift 5

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you have any idea about the runtime safety of different patch versions that don't produce a compiler error?

Comment: @AdamJohns not sure about that, it depends on what compiler level the Swift team will make the changes.

Comment: Especially given they are actively working toward ABI stability, the assumption should lean towards things _not_ being compatible. Until (at least) 5.0 I would avoid any tooling that can't be updated.

Comment: What about patches (e.g. Swift 5.0 and 5.0.1, 4.2 and 4.2.1)? Are they guaranteed to be both ABI stable and Module stable (which is not even yet the case with Swift 5: https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-module-stability-and-module-interface-files/23337)

Comment: @WernerAltewischer Module stability is scheduled for Swift 6. Regarding patches, Swift 5.x will be ABI stable in regards to Swift Standard Library only.

Comment: @Cristik Swift module stability provided with Xcode11. We have now swift-module-interface files

Comment: Thanks for pinging on this, @Erhan, I added details about the `.swiftinterface` files in the answer.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not so sure the `-enable-library-evolution` flag is related to module stability. Seems like that is more related to ABI stability and should really only affect people like Apple that ship frameworks with the OS (not packaged inside an app). Reference: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0260-library-evolution.md.

Comment: @AdamJohns this is an excerpt from the swift forums links I posted: "There is still one big limitation: .swiftinterface files require -enable-library-evolution". So, in order to use `.swiftinterface` files, it seems you need this flag.

Comment: @Cristik, yeah I'm a little confused. I can't seem to figure out how statements like that one fit in with statements like [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0260-library-evolution.md): "These considerations should not affect libraries shipped with their clients, including SwiftPM packages. These libraries should always have library evolution mode turned off"

Comment: Also from your link: "Even though you don't need the full ABI compatibility guarantee because of the bundling with the final app, someone else might make a binary framework of their own that depends on yours, and ideally their framework wouldn't be revlocked with yours.". This seems to imply you only really need the flag if someone consumes your binary framework in their binary framework.

Comment: Also, [this link](https://medium.com/swiftify/swift-5-1-module-format-stability-best-time-migrate-objective-c-frameworks-a0434f5352a3) suggests library evolution is only needed if you change a framework without re-compiling the client application (e.g. an Apple framework shipped with the OS).

Comment: @AdamJohns but isn't this the main goal of ABI stability? To allow already compiled libraries to interoperate regardless the Swift version they were built with? So in order to have full ABI stability, you need that flag, otherwise you only have partial stability. Or is this how I see it :)

Comment: Stumbled too upon a very good article explaining ABI vs Module stability: https://www.donnywals.com/what-is-module-stability-in-swift-and-why-should-you-care/ - I might have to expand my answer a little bit :) (@AdamJohns)

Answer (score 2):

I think we should know what is ABI stability firstly, After that your confusion has already been removed.

Today, the latest version of Swift is 3.1, so chances are if you ship an app tomorrow, your app bundle will contain the Swift dynamic libraries for 3.1, however, there are plenty of apps in the store right now which link 3.0, 2.3, and probably even some older apps that link 2.1 and earlier. Nothing is stopping me from downloading your app (on 3.1) and my app (on 2.3) and running them side-by-side on my iPhone with iOS 10.3, since both apps link against their own bundled version of Swift. It's exactly the same as you bundling Alamofire 4.4 and while I bundle 3.0.

When a language is ABI-stable (Application Binary Interface), that means it is packaged and linked with the operating system itself, in this case: iOS. The Swift code you compile on your computer has a binary interface into the operating system itself rather than any dynamic library you bundle with your application. Because of this, Apple has to be able to guarantee that my Swift code, when compiled to machine code (bitcode, LLVM-IR, yada-yada), will be able to interface properly with the rest of the operating system, and (probably more importantly) will not break between versions of iOS / Swift.

As it stands today, the Swift language specification and compiler are not in a state where the Swift team would feel comfortable making this promise of ABI-stability; changes to Swift are still too frequent and the roadmap is still too long. As soon as the Swift library is merged into iOS, it becomes much much harder to make big changes.

### Why does it matter?

- Yes, the bundle size of your application will decrease because you will no longer have to include the Swift standard library in your Frameworks folder, which is nice.
- Language changes will be smaller / less frequent, so you won't have to worry about events like migration from Swift 2 -> 3 (I'm still scarred from that)
- Developers will be able to create 3rd-party libraries written in Swift and distribute pre-compiled frameworks (binaries), because they no longer need to bundle the Swift standard library into their framework, and will instead be linking against the same version of Swift as your app (the one packaged with iOS).